# JS for views embedded in cached blocks broken.. console.log(Drupal); doesn't even have 'views' array

Tags: views, caching

I've been trying to hunt down the cause of this for a while now..

I have `views_embed_view` in various blocks and with block cache enabled, the pagers etc. are broken..

I thought it might be something do with my block template so reverted it to standard (theme: Framework), and my views templates are normal as well. But when I check the Drupal variable in console on a page with the blocks cached, there isn't even a 'views' in the array.

All of the other answers on Drupal seem to talk about mismatched dom IDs but I don't even have that.

Chosen is also missing and its js isn't loaded on the page.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more info. I have almost no idea what the problem is here.

Comment: I have views embedded in a block, and when the block is cached, the JS for pager / calendar pager / exposed filters is broken. I'm wondering if there's some way to reattached behaviors or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use #attached https://montanaprogrammer.com/2012/11/19/drupal-block-add-js-css/

```
$block['subject'] = t('Testing block');
$block['content'] = array(
  '#markup' => mymodule_testblock_content(),
  '#attached' => array(
     'css' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule.css',
    ),
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't work for the Views pagers etc. But it did work for a Highcharts View which now works while cached so thanks for that. I'm just gonna create custom pagers etc. for the broken views and load new views with Ajax instead. It will end up being a "nicer" solution anyways.